# How to deploy application from AzureDevOps to custom VM inside Azure?

Tags: azure, docker, deployment, azure-devops

I'am using AzureDevOps to build and pack my docker application.

The goal is to execute docker-compose commands in Azure VM, which is behind the firewall and can be access only thru vpn connection or standard web-browsing ports.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azdevops#deploy-agents-to-a-deployment-group) to achieve that. Reason this will work, because it is a one way communication (from agent to Azure Devops), so you dont really need to open ports for the VM, the VM has to only be able to reach Azure Devops endspoints ([more on this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azdevops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with)).

TLDR. Using agents will work, because its an outgoing connection from the agent, not from Azure Devops to the agent.

Comment: Thanks, for helping me out. I managed to solve my situation using your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. :) Thanks again